# Angular.js organize controllers into App namespace

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm starting to use Angular.js on a new project and from the basic tutorials, I see mostly a single controllers.js file that contains all the controller functions, each which are bound to the window object.

It seems that a better practice would be use the existing "myApp" namespace, to add controllers to, for example:

```
myApp.controllers = {};
myApp.controllers.userItem = function($scope) {}
```

All controllers would be part of the created "myApp.controllers" object or "window.myApp.controllers".

Does anyone suggest a better or more organized way to handle controllers or other item, custom services, directives, etc. would use the same structure.

In addition to this, I'm debating about putting each controller into it's own file, which ultimately would be combined for production, but depending on the size of the app, it may be a bit overkill and only cause more work bouncing around between files.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Great question!

I don't like that the tutorials and documentation take a "package-by-layers" approach to their code. I think that is probably done for convenience in teaching concepts, which is great, but that approach has limited applicability in the real world.

Package-by-feature is a far better approach:

```
|- README
|- src/
   |- app/
      |- app.js
      |- feature1/
      |- feature2/
      |- ...
   |- vendor/
      |- angular/
      |- bootstrap/
      |- ...
   |- assets/
   |- less/
   |- index.html
```

Inside `src/app`, you can package your contents based on the section of the site you're working on (e.g. menus) and by routes (e.g. product list and product detail). Each can be declared like so:

```js
angular.module( 'products', [
  'productCatalog',
  ...
])
```

And each module can have its own routes:

```js
.config( [ '$routeProvider', function( $routeProvider ) {
  $routeProvider.when( '/products', { ... } );
  $routeProvider.when( '/products/:id', { ... } );
});
```

And controllers, etc:

```js
.controller( 'ProductListCtrl', [ '$scope', function ( $scope ) { ... } ]);
```

So everything that goes together is packaged in the same directory. And you can place all of your components in separate files, with one module per file (if you wish; I usually do). And in your top-level app, you simply declare your dependencies:

```js
angular.module( 'app', [
  'products',
  ...
]);
```

You can also bundle general-purpose directives by themselves, too, to keep your tests and documentation all together - again, by feature! And each of these components are drag-and-drop reusable in future projects.

A great reference implementation is [angular-app](http://github.com/angular-app/angular-app). Check it out!

**Update:** Since this answer, I started an AngularJS project kickstarter/template called [ngBoilerplate](http://joshdmiller.github.com/ng-boilerplate) to encapsulate these concepts (among many other best practices) and a sophisticated build system to support them.

Comment: @acme I'm glad you found it helpful! I also added a link to [ngBoilerplate](http://bit.ly/ngBoilerplate), which is a build system and project template for new AngularJS projects.

Comment: I love that.  In the spirit of keeping all related items together, what do you think about having the tests for that module within the same directory?

Comment: @Vishal I strongly support putting sources, tests, styles, and templates all together, organized as reusable components. :-)

Answer (score 2):

I usually do

```
(angular
 .module('app.controllers', ['ng', ...])
 .controller('myContrA', [
     /******/ '$scope',
     function ($scope) {
     }
 ])
 .controller('myContrB', [
     /******/ '$scope',
     function ($scope) {
     }
 ])
);
```

This way you can add `app.controllers` as a dependency and thus make all your controllers available.

Comment: I like the look of this, but when I call my app config function where I set up routes, all of my controllers are undefined

Comment: It always tells me "app.controllers is an Unknown provider"

Comment: you need to list the `app.controllers` module name in the dependencies for your application module.

Comment: Thanks! You know what the actual problem was that in my Router, I was referencing my controllers as variables instead of Strings. So it was  { controller: MyOldGlobalControllerName }, but when you do it this way it needs to be a string { controller: 'MyOldGlobalControllerName' } - thanks!

Comment: This goes against the angular best practices, both in the AngularJS team's Best Practices section (https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Best-Practices) and the commonly-used community-driven style guide by John Papa.  Quick quote from the former: "Instead of slicing your app across horizontals that can't be broken up, group your code into related bundles. [...] app.controllers, app.services, etc will break your app if you remove a module [...] app.users, app.users.edit, app.users.admin, app.projects, etc allows you to group related components."

Comment: I think package-by-feature is a more viable way to go for larger applications.